# Opening a PDF file from binary data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, post, binary

I'm using an XMLHttpRequest object to POST data to the server to generate a PDF from the data I posted to the server.

When the PDF is done generating the resultHandler function in my JavaScript gets called with the binary contents of the PDF file as the parameter.

My question is, how do I open the actual PDF (binary data) to display it in the browser?

```
/**
 * Posts a HTTP request to the request url.
 * Sets the request result handler.
 */
function xmlHttpRequest(url, resultHandler, postData)
{
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            try
            {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
            resultHandler(xmlHttp.response);
        }
    }

    // Opens the loader overlay
    openLoader();

    xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);

    // Check if data should be sent
    if(postData == null)
    {
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlHttp.send(postData);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should create a url of ur Pdf file and and send as a Server responce and just show as new tab or same window.

Comment: The file has no physical location on a server, it stored as binary data in a database and gets sent through to the front-end as binary data.